# how to change radio buttons original color on dbclick in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button

If I click on radio button ,color changes to yellow,but if I double click on it, I want its original color i.e gray.
How should I do this?

`JS`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input:radio').change(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.closest('.box').find('div.highlight').removeClass('highlight');
        $this.closest('.q').addClass('highlight');
    });
});
```

`CSS`

```
.q {
    background: #ccc;
    margin: 10 px;
}

.highlight {
    background: #FC0;
}
```

`HTML`

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="q">
        <input type="radio" id="1" name="11" />
        <label for 1>Radio Button1</label>
    </div>
    <div class="q">
        <input type="radio" id="2" name="11" /`enter code here`>
        <label for 1>Radio Button2</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

use dblclick and click event

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input:radio').click(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.closest('.box').find('div.highlight').removeClass('highlight');
        $this.closest('.q').addClass('highlight');
    })
    .dblclick(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.closest('.box').find('div.highlight').removeClass('highlight');
        $this.closest('.q').removeClass('highlight');
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Why not use  `toggleClass` ?

Comment: toggleClass can be used as well :)